# Projeto android não deleta registro no banco de dados Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-permission

Minha aplicação faz inserções e leitura dos registros existentes no banco SQLite, mas quando vou executar um `delete` tenho a seguinte mensagem de log:

> W/FileUtils: Failed to chmod(/storage/sdcard/Cardapio
>   Digital/Database/dbcardapio.sqlite): android.system.ErrnoException:
>   chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)

minhas permissões no manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

minha classe de acesso a dados:

```
public class PedidosDao {

    Context context;
    variaveis v;
    SQLiteDatabase db;


    public PedidosDao(Context context, variaveis v) {
        this.v = v;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void deletaItem(int codigo){
        db = context.openOrCreateDatabase(v.getPathBanco(),Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE,null);

        try{

            db.execSQL("DELETE FROM PEDIDOS WHERE ID = "+codigo);

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        db.close();
    }
```